# Why does Esperanto use Ĉ instead of Č?

Tags: writing

If I'm not mistaken the "capped" letters come from how Slavic languages are transliterated/written using the Latin alphabet, so why is the ĉ used instead of č when Slavic languages would use the former rather than the latter? Also they generally use ž instead of ĵ, so why is ĵ used?

Using Serbian romanization:

ч > č instead of ĉ

џ > dž instead of ĝ

х  > h instead of ĥ (why not 'ȟ'?)

ж > ž instead of ĵ

ш > š instead of ŝ

ў > ŭ? instead of ŭ

using this system
"eĥoŝanĝo ĉiuĵaŭde"
would be:
"eȟošandžo čiužaŭde"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why "hats" (circumflexes, `ˆ`) instead of carons (`ˇ`)?

> If I'm not mistaken The "capped" letters come from how slavic languages are transliterated/written using the latin alphabet, so why is the ĉ used instead of č when slavic languages would use the former rather than the latter?

According to [section *"origin"* of the article *"Esperanto orthography"* in the English wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Esperanto_orthography&oldid=978912936#Origin):

> The script resembles Western Slavic Latin alphabets but uses [circumflexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex) instead of [carons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) for the letters *ĉ*, *ĝ*, *ĥ*, *ĵ*, and *ŝ*. [...]
>
> Zamenhof took advantage of the fact that typewriters for the French language (which, in his lifetime, was still a kind of international *lingua franca* for educated people) possess a dead key for the circumflex and umlaut/diaeresis diacritics: thus, anyone who could avail himself of a French typewriter could type ĉ ĝ ĥ ĵ ŝ and their uppercase counterparts with no problem.

#### Why `ĵ` instead of `ž` (or `ẑ`)?

> Also they generally use ž instead of ĵ, so why is ĵ used?

According to the [same Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Esperanto_orthography&oldid=978912936#Origin):

> Also, the non-Slavic bases of the letters *ĝ* and *ĵ*, rather than Slavic *dž* and *ž*, help preserve the printed appearance of Latinate and Germanic vocabulary such as *ĝenerala* "general" (adjective) and *ĵurnalo* "journal".

Comment: I did read that before, but I guess I had forgotten. Ĝ is better for dʒ anyway, since dž would be 2 letters for that sound instead of one.